# *** Solved *** Running GUILD on a MacBook gives an Attribute Error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[Update]
I was able to solve error that came up after
I commented out the windll lines as suggested by Bryan Oakley. Another error was displayed:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'background.png'
```

I was able to fix that error by adding the complete path that Finder's "Get info" gave me. Now the program generates the code on my MacBook.

*** Original Post ***
I'm very new to Python and would like to use a program called GUILD that allows the user to create GUI screens in Figma and export it as Python coding for tkinter. The program is also written in Python and the developer's info for the program is at: [Link to GUILD](https://github.com/saksham-lussqvx/G.U.I.L.D/blob/main/README.md)

After installing the program based according to the instructions given by the program's developer, I tried to run the program and it gave me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'
```

After doing a Google search, I found out that the GUILD program is calling windll which is only for Window operating systems. GUILD is open source so I would like to know if you can look at the coding from GUILD and let me know if it's possible to change the coding so it will run on my MacBook and exactly what coding needs to be changed?

quild.py coding for GUILD:

```
# Made by @Saksham Solanki, Date: 18/06/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY), Time: 22:24 (24-hour-format)
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import ctypes
from tkinter.constants import W

import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)


class gui_properties:
    def get_color(element):
        # Returns HEX form of element RGB color (str)
        el_r = element["fills"][0]["color"]['r'] * 255
        el_g = element["fills"][0]["color"]['g'] * 255
        el_b = element["fills"][0]["color"]['b'] * 255

        return ('#%02x%02x%02x' % (round(el_r), round(el_g), round(el_b)))

    def get_line_color(element):
        # Returns HEX form of element RGB color (str)
        el_r = element["strokes"][0]["color"]['r'] * 255
        el_g = element["strokes"][0]["color"]['g'] * 255
        el_b = element["strokes"][0]["color"]['b'] * 255

        return ('#%02x%02x%02x' % (round(el_r), round(el_g), round(el_b)))

    def get_coordinates(element):
        # Returns element coordinates as x (int) and y (int)
        x = int(element["absoluteBoundingBox"]["x"])
        y = int(element["absoluteBoundingBox"]["y"])
        x = x + (x*25/100)
        y = y + (y*25/100)
        return int(x), int(y)

    def get_dimensions(element):
        # Return element dimensions as width (int) and height (int)
        height = int(element["absoluteBoundingBox"]["height"])
        width = int(element["absoluteBoundingBox"]["width"])
        width = width + (width*25/100)
        height = height + (height*25/100)
        return int(width), int(height)

    def get_dimensions_entrybox(entrybox):
        # Return dimensions of entrybox type element
        height = int(entrybox["absoluteBoundingBox"]["height"])
        width = int(entrybox["absoluteBoundingBox"]["width"])
        height = int((height*6)/100)
        width = int((width*12.45)/100)
        return int(width), int(height)

    def get_text_properties(element):
        # Return element font and fontSize (str)
        font = element["style"]["fontFamily"]
        fontSize = element["style"]["fontSize"]
        fontSize = str(int((int(fontSize)*78.75)/100))

        return font, fontSize

    def get_alignment(element):
        align = element["style"]["textAlignHorizontal"]
        if align == 'LEFT':
            return 'left'
        elif align == 'RIGHT':
            return 'right'
        elif align == 'CENTER':
            return 'center'
        elif align == 'JUSTIFIED':
            return "none"


class conversion:
    def background(element, file_id, token, gen_dir):
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        item_id = element["id"]

        response = requests.get(
            f"https://api.figma.com/v1/images/{file_id}"
            f"?ids={item_id}&use_absolute_bounds=true",
            headers={"X-FIGMA-TOKEN": f"{token}"})

        image_link = requests.get(response.json()["images"][item_id])

        with open(f"{gen_dir}background.png", "wb") as file:
            file.write(image_link.content)

        lines.extend(['\n\n# Background of window (bg.png should be in same folder as this file)',
                      'img = Image.open("background.png")',
                      'bg_image = img.resize((int(img.width+(img.width*25/100)), int(img.height+(img.height*25/100))))',
                      'bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg_image)',
                      f'tk.Label(window, image=bg_image, borderwidth=0, relief="solid").place(x={x},y={y})'])

    def picture(element, elements, file_id, token, gen_dir):
        count_1
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        item_id = element["id"]

        response = requests.get(
            f"https://api.figma.com/v1/images/{file_id}"
            f"?ids={item_id}&use_absolute_bounds=true",
            headers={"X-FIGMA-TOKEN": f"{token}"})

        image_link = requests.get(response.json()["images"][item_id])

        with open(f"{gen_dir}picture_{count_1}.png", "wb") as file:
            file.write(image_link.content)
        bg = "#FFFFFF"
        for ele in elements:
            if ele["name"] == "Picture_color_"+element["name"][-1:]:
                bg = gui_properties.get_color(ele)
        lines.extend(['\n\n# Picutre (image should be in same folder as this file)',
                      f'img_{count_1} = Image.open("picture_{count_1}.png")',
                      f'img_{count_1} = img_{count_1}.resize((int(img_{count_1}.width+(img_{count_1}.width*25/100)), int(img_{count_1}.height+(img_{count_1}.height*25/100))))',
                      f'pic_{count_1} = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_{count_1})',
                      f'tk.Label(window, image=pic_{count_1}, bg="{bg}",borderwidth=0, relief="solid").place(x={x},y={y})'])

    def menubutton(element, elements):
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        element_color = gui_properties.get_color(element)
        for ele in elements:
            if ele["name"] == "Menubox_text_"+element["name"][-1:]:
                text = ele["characters"]
                color = gui_properties.get_color(ele)
                font, fontSize = gui_properties.get_text_properties(ele)
        lines.extend(['\n\n# MenuBox',
                      f'\nMenuBox_{count_4} = tk.Menubutton(window, text="{text}", font=("{font}", {fontSize}), bg="{element_color}", fg="{color}", activebackground="{element_color}", activeforeground="{color}")',
                      f'MenuBox_{count_4}.place(x={x}, y={y})',
                      f'MenuBox_{count_4}.menu = tk.Menu(MenuBox_{count_4}, tearoff=0)',
                      f'MenuBox_{count_4}["menu"] = MenuBox_{count_4}.menu'],
                     )
        for value in elements:
            if value["name"] == "Menubox_list_"+element["name"][-1:]:
                vals = value["characters"]
                vals = vals.splitlines()
                vals2 = [line.replace(" ", "_") for line in vals]
                for menu_val in vals2:
                    lines.extend([f'{menu_val} = tk.IntVar()',
                                 f'MenuBox_{count_4}.menu.add_checkbutton(label="{menu_val}", variable={menu_val})'])

    def text(element, elements):
        bg = "#FFFFFF"
        ele_name = element["name"].split("_")
        suffix = ele_name[1]
        for color in elements:
            if "Text_color_"+suffix in color["name"]:
                bg = gui_properties.get_color(color)
        text = element["characters"]
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        color = gui_properties.get_color(element)
        font, fontSize = gui_properties.get_text_properties(element)
        align = gui_properties.get_alignment(element)
        text = text.replace("\n", "\\n")
        if align == "none":
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Text'
                          f'\ntk.Label(window, text="{text}", font=("{font}", {fontSize}), bg="{bg}",fg="{color}").place(x={x}, y={y})'])
        else:
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Text'
                          f'\ntk.Label(window, text="{text}", font=("{font}", {fontSize}), justify="{align}", bg="{bg}",fg="{color}").place(x={x}, y={y})'])

    def frames(element):
        width, height = gui_properties.get_dimensions(element)
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        element_color = gui_properties.get_color(element)

        lines.extend(['\n\n# Frame',
                      f'tk.Frame(window, bg="{element_color}", width={width}, height={height}).place(x={x}, y={y})'])

    def entryBox(element, elements):
        width, height = gui_properties.get_dimensions_entrybox(element)
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        color = gui_properties.get_color(element)
        y = str(int(y) + 5)
        text = ""
        for txt in elements:
            if "Entrybox_text_"+element["name"][-1:] == txt["name"]:
                text = txt["characters"]
                text_color = gui_properties.get_color(txt)
                font, fontsize = gui_properties.get_text_properties(txt)
        if len(text) > 0:
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Entrybox',
                          f'entrybox_{count_2} = tk.Text(window, width={width}, height={height}, bg="{color}", fg="{text_color}", font=("{font}", {fontsize}))',
                          f'entrybox_{count_2}.insert(1.0, "{text}")',
                          f'entrybox_{count_2}.place(x={x}, y={y})'])
        else:
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Entrybox',
                          f'entrybox_{count_2} = tk.Text(window, width={width}, height={height}, bg="{color}")',
                          f'entrybox_{count_2}.place(x={x}, y={y})'])

    def line(element):
        width, height = gui_properties.get_dimensions(element)
        x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
        color = gui_properties.get_line_color(element)
        if int(width) == 0:
            width = 1

        lines.extend(['\n\n# Line',
                      f'tk.Frame(window, width={width}, height={height}, bg="{color}").place(x={x}, y={y})'])

    def button(element, elements, token, file_id, gen_dir):
        Type = element["name"].split('_')[1]
        if Type == 'NR':
            x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
            color = gui_properties.get_color(element)
            text = ""
            for ele in elements:
                if ele["name"] == "B_"+element["name"][-1:]:
                    text = ele["characters"]
                    font, fontsize = gui_properties.get_text_properties(ele)
                    text_color = gui_properties.get_color(ele)
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Button',
                          f'button_{count_3} = tk.Button(window, text="{text}", bg="{color}", fg="{text_color}", activebackground="{color}", activeforeground="{text_color}", relief="flat", command=lambda:[placeholder()], font=("{font}", {fontsize}))',
                          f'button_{count_3}.place(x={x}, y={y})'])
        if Type == 'R':
            item_id = element["id"]

            response = requests.get(
                f"https://api.figma.com/v1/images/{file_id}"
                f"?ids={item_id}&use_absolute_bounds=true",
                headers={"X-FIGMA-TOKEN": f"{token}"})

            image_link = requests.get(response.json()["images"][item_id])

            with open(f"{gen_dir}button_{count_3}.png", "wb") as file:
                file.write(image_link.content)
            color = "#ffffff"
            for ele in elements:
                if ele["name"] == "BR_color_"+element["name"][-1:]:
                    color = gui_properties.get_color(ele)
            x, y = gui_properties.get_coordinates(element)
            lines.extend(['\n\n# Button',
                          f'img_b_{count_3} = Image.open("button_{count_3}.png")',
                          f'img_b_{count_3} = img_b_{count_3}.resize((int(img_b_{count_3}.width+(img_b_{count_3}.width*25/100)), int(img_b_{count_3}.height+(img_b_{count_3}.height*25/100))))',
                          f'pic_b_{count_3} = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_b_{count_3})',
                          f'button_{count_3} = tk.Button(window, image = pic_b_{count_3}, activebackground="{color}", bg="{color}", relief="flat", command=lambda:[placeholder()])',
                          f'button_{count_3}.place(x={x}, y={y})'])

    def save(gen_dir):
        lines.extend(['window.resizable(False, False)', 'window.mainloop()'])
        final_code = [line + "\n" for line in lines]

        with open(f"{gen_dir}window.py", 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as py_file:
            py_file.writelines(final_code)
        messagebox.showinfo("Converted", "The code has been generated")

    def main():  # sourcery no-metrics
        token = entrybox_0.get('1.0', tk.END)
        link = entrybox_1.get('1.0', tk.END)
        token = token.splitlines()[0]
        link = link.splitlines()[0]
        file = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=window, initialdir="/")
        generated_dir = file + "/output/"
        global lines
        lines = []
        lines.extend(['import tkinter as tk\nimport ctypes\nfrom PIL import Image, ImageTk\n\nctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)\n\n',
                      'def placeholder():',
                      '    print("Your function comes here")\n\n',
                      '# Window Initialization',
                      'window = tk.Tk()',
                      'window.title("Window")'])

        def find_between(s, first, last):
            try:
                start = s.index(first) + len(first)
                end = s.index(last, start)

                return s[start:end]

            except ValueError:
                return ""

        token = token.strip()
        file_url = link.strip()

        file_id = find_between(file_url, "file/", "/")
        try:
            response = requests.get(
                f"https://api.figma.com/v1/files/{file_id}", headers={"X-FIGMA-TOKEN": token})
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Value Error", "Either token or the file seems to be wrong")

        except requests.ConnectionError:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "No Connection", "No Internet connection detected")

        elements = response.json()
        try:
            fig_window = elements["document"]["children"][0]["children"][0]

            try:
                os.mkdir(generated_dir)

            except FileExistsError:
                messagebox.showinfo(
                    "File Exists", "Existing Files will be overwritten.")

            except PermissionError:
                messagebox.showerror(
                    "Permission Error", "Change directory or directory permissions.")

        except KeyError:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Error", "Invalid Input. Please check your input and try again.")

        except IndexError:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Error", "Invalid design file. Does your file contain a Frame?")

        window_width, window_height = gui_properties.get_dimensions(fig_window)

        try:
            window_bg_hex = gui_properties.get_color(fig_window)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            window_bg_hex = "#FFFFFF"

        lines.extend([f'window.geometry("{window_width}x{window_height}")',
                      f'window.configure(bg = "{window_bg_hex}")'])

        # Getting Elements inside Window

        window_elements = fig_window["children"]
        global count_1, count_2, count_3, count_4
        count_1 = 0
        count_2 = 0
        count_3 = 0
        count_4 = 0

        for element in window_elements:
            if element["name"] == "Background":
                conversion.background(element, file_id, token, generated_dir)
            elif element["name"] == "Frame":
                conversion.frames(element)
            elif "Picture" in element["name"] and "color" not in element["name"]:
                conversion.picture(element, window_elements,
                                   file_id, token, generated_dir)
                count_1 += 1
            elif "Text" in element["name"] and "color" not in element["name"]:
                conversion.text(element, window_elements)
            elif "Entrybox" in element["name"] and "text" not in element["name"]:
                conversion.entryBox(element, window_elements)
                count_2 += 1
            elif "Menubox" in element["name"] and "text" not in element["name"] and "list" not in element["name"]:
                conversion.menubutton(element, window_elements)
                count_4 += 1
            elif element["name"] == "Line":
                conversion.line(element)
            elif "Button" in element["name"]:
                conversion.button(element, window_elements,
                                  token, file_id, generated_dir)
                count_3 += 1
        conversion.save(generated_dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Window Initialization
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Window")
    window.geometry("1250x625")
    window.configure(bg = "#ffffff")


    # Background of window (bg.png should be in same folder as this file)
    img = Image.open("background.png")
    bg_image = img.resize((int(img.width+(img.width*25/100)), int(img.height+(img.height*25/100))))
    bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg_image)
    tk.Label(window, image=bg_image, borderwidth=0, relief="solid").place(x=0,y=0)


    # Frame
    tk.Frame(window, bg="#ffffff", width=1125, height=525).place(x=62, y=58)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="GUI", font=("Comic Sans MS", 23), justify="left", bg="#FFFFFF",fg="#000000").place(x=72, y=58)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="LD", font=("Comic Sans MS", 23), justify="left", bg="#FFFFFF",fg="#2b2bff").place(x=151, y=58)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="WELCOME TO GRAPHICAL\nUSER INTERFACE\nLAYOUT DESIGNER", font=("Roboto", 23), justify="left", bg="#FFFFFF",fg="#000000").place(x=121, y=145)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="Build eye pleasing GUI’s under minutes with\nsimple drag and drop interface of your\nproject without any hastle of debugging and\nmodifying code again and again!", font=("Courier New", 11), justify="left", bg="#FFFFFF",fg="#000000").place(x=121, y=342)


    # Picutre (image should be in same folder as this file)
    img_0 = Image.open("picture_0.png")
    img_0 = img_0.resize((int(img_0.width+(img_0.width*25/100)), int(img_0.height+(img_0.height*25/100))))
    pic_0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_0)
    tk.Label(window, image=pic_0, bg="#FFFFFF",borderwidth=0, relief="solid").place(x=705,y=123)


    # Line
    tk.Frame(window, width=1, height=415, bg="#000000").place(x=656, y=110)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="Token ID:", font=("Roboto", 15), justify="left", bg="#3f3f3f",fg="#7e7e7e").place(x=755, y=210)


    # Text
    tk.Label(window, text="File  Link:", font=("Roboto", 15), justify="left", bg="#3f3f3f",fg="#7e7e7e").place(x=755, y=287)


    # Entrybox
    entrybox_0 = tk.Text(window, width=18, height=1, bg="#ffffff")
    entrybox_0.place(x=901, y=216)


    # Entrybox
    entrybox_1 = tk.Text(window, width=18, height=1, bg="#ffffff")
    entrybox_1.place(x=901, y=293)


    # Button
    img_b_0 = Image.open("button_0.png")
    img_b_0 = img_b_0.resize((int(img_b_0.width+(img_b_0.width*25/100)), int(img_b_0.height+(img_b_0.height*25/100))))
    pic_b_0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_b_0)
    button_0 = tk.Button(window, image = pic_b_0, activebackground="#3f3f3f", bg="#3f3f3f", relief="flat", command=lambda:[conversion.main()])
    button_0.place(x=828, y=396)
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried simply commenting out any code that references windll?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just commented out the windll lines and another error appeared stating: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'background.png'. I checked the folder where GUILD was located and background.png was in that folder so I'm not sure why it's telling me that file was not found.

Comment: I was able to get the program to run. It was giving me that error if I tried to run it from Visual Studio Code but it did run from Terminal, however it gave a lot of additional errors. I will update the post to include the details of those errors as well.